# Sensitivity analysis: How do I perform the adjoint method?

Tags: structural-engineering, dynamics, vibration

Suppose I have a rectangular plate (width $a$, height $b$, thickness $t$). By using a Finite-Element discretization I obtain the system

$M \ddot{x} + Kx= f$

with mass matrix $M$, stiffness matrix $K$ and force vector $f$. Now I want to know whether the solution vector $x$ does change if I vary $a,b$ or $t$; this is called sensitivity analysis. I know the direct method, but the adjoint method is also known. How I obtain the sensitivities by the adjoint method?

I did not understand this method well after I looked in literature.

Comment: This question has been addressed in the scicomp stack exchange website.  If you have more specific questions regarding a particular aspect of implementing the adjoint method, please post a new question there. Check this post in particular:  http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/14259/understanding-the-cost-of-adjoint-method-for-pde-constrained-optimization